# HTML Portfolio Open Text Box After Performing Clickable Action

Tags: html, portfolio

So I'm making a portfolio for my applications and am having trouble understanding some logic in my code. I'm not well versed in HTML but could do the basics except for this last part. Here's the code snippet below and later I'll describe what I'm trying to do.

Code:

```
<div class="isotope-item">
  <figure class="snip1321">
    <img
      src="assets/images/portfolio-01.jpg"
      alt="sq-sample26"
    />
    <figcaption>
      <a
        href="assets/images/portfolio-01.jpg"
        data-lightbox="image-1"
        data-title="Caption"
        ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
        <h4>FPS</h4>
      <span>Game Design</span>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

My goal is to have an image and once hovered over, to display an icon, the project name and a short description which it does. What I want it to do now is once the icon is clicked, it opens up more info about the project via text as well as a link to the project (on GitHub). All it does is open the image back up again along with the data title underneath the picture being "Caption" but I want MORE than just the caption and I don't want that image popping up again but rather maybe a white box of text along with the clickable link.

Here are the images of what I'm talking about:
[Clickable Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBuS7.jpg)
[Result after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de3On.png)

I tried removing the href in the figcaption block to get rid of the image which prompted my loading image (data-lightbox) so I removed both of those and then the search icon would not be hoverable. Then I tried adding

blocks at various points in the code but all would either put it in the preview on top of the caption, inside the caption, or outside rather than after being clicked. I'm wondering if this is where I can make the modification or if it's located elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe just use a lightbox script like Fancybox.